# Why Nextflow pipeline don't find a file?

Tags: nextflow

I'm traying to launch a Nextflow pipeline, but it throws the following error:

```
ERROR ~ No signature of method: groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataflowBroadcast.into() is applicable for argument types: (Script_dd34529ec87c0dd2$_runScript_closure3) values: [Script_dd34529ec87c0dd2$_runScript_closure3@39652a30]
Possible solutions: any(), find(), bind(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter), find(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

The error is thrown by this part of the code:

```
Channel
    .fromFilePairs("$root/**/*.trk", size: -1) { it.parent.name }
    .into{ tractogram; tractogram_for_check } // [sid, tractogram.trk]
```

I think the problem is that it can't find the file, but it is in the correct folder and has the correct name and extension. How could I solve it?
The GitHub source code of [this pipeline](https://github.com/scil-vital/fiesta).

Comment: Damn, that's a tricky script to break apart. DSL1, and lots of `**` in paths makes thing pretty inefficient. They also don't say what version of Nextflow they used, so you may need to rewrite some of this unfortunately. 

I'm a little confused what file pairs are meant to be read in as there is no `{x,y}` notation which is usually used. See docs [here](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#fromfilepairs). What are the 2 files means to be read in? 
If you can provide more detail about the input and file structure, I may be able to help.

Comment: It is supposed to look for a .trk file and the parent directory of the file. The .trk files contain three-dimensional data about a patient's brain. You can find these files in a main folder where all the patients' data is stored. Each patient has their own folder within this main folder, and inside each patient's folder, you'll find various files, including the .trk files. For example, the path to a .trk file for a patient named "patient1" would be 'root/patient1/*.trk'.

Comment: I still don't know why `fromFilePairs` is used, not do I know what other files are needed. Why do you need the parent directory path? Can you not just read the necessary files into a process by making more appropriate channels?

Comment: The thing is, this isn't my code; I'm just trying to use it. In case it's useful, when launching the pipeline, you need to specify the root path where all the different files are located, which in my example, is the root.

Comment: Well, then there isn't much others can do to help if you don't even understand the basics of their pipeline. Often you will find tools like this that you need to pull apart and adapt, but this requires investing time to figure out what it's doing.

Comment: Yeah, tahnk you anyways.